# How to regenerate an initramfs with ash built-in shell?

Tags: debian, xen, initramfs

I foolishly edited my `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` and now my computer won't boot. It drops down to (initramfs). It claims it cannot find the root device. However, cat /proc/cmdline shows the correct UUID of root. So I am 90% certain my boot issue is due to my mkinitcpio edit. (not to mention this happened the next boot after the edit).

How do I regenerate the initramfs image so that I may boot properly once again?

Comment: /etc/mkinitcpio.conf is only on arch. I am no longer sure what I edited. To "fix" my issue I booted from a flashdrive iso, mounted my HDD, and transferred all the data I needed to my server. I then completely re-installed my OS.